# Netty HttpStaticFileServer example not working with HttpContentCompressor

Tags: java, netty

If I add the following line to [HttpStaticFileServerInitializer](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/file/HttpStaticFileServerInitializer.java)

```
pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(65536));
pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
pipeline.addLast("chunkedWriter", new ChunkedWriteHandler());
pipeline.addLast("deflater", new HttpContentCompressor());  // Added
```

The files get served with `Content-Encoding: gzip` but the content is not actually gzipped.  This causes most browsers to fail decoding the content.

Does `DefaultFileRegion` not work with `HttpContentCompressor`, or is there something else one must do to get them to work together?

Comment: This works at my side. Any more information?

Comment: I cloned the netty git repo, added the deflater line as shown above, and run the example.  View http://localhost:8080 in a browser and select a file and Chrome will report 'This webpage is unavailable' with Error code: ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED, because the Content-Encoding: gzip header is present but the content is not gzipped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get chunked transfers (ChunkedWriteHandler) and HttpContentCompressor to work together. You simple need to provide a ChunkedInput which generates **HttpContent** objects instead of **ByteBuf** ones.

Here's a quick write-up:
http://andreas.haufler.info/2014/01/making-http-content-compression-work-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, chunked transfer and gzip content encoding are are a difficult combination. The compression must not be done at the chunk level but on the whole content (making it impossible for live data). Thus, you need to zip the content yourself and then transfer it. In your example, it means you can't use in combination, the chunk writer and the content compressor.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Clement's comment and subsequent discussion in **#netty** it sounds like it is **not possible** to use `DefaultFileRegion` and `HttpContentCompressor` together.  I switched back to `ChunkedFile` and it works fine.

```
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
    if (request.method() != HttpMethod.HEAD) {
        ctx.write(new ChunkedFile(raf, 0, fileLength, 8192));
    }
```

I also subclassed `HttpContentCompressor` and do a bit of checking against the content type to determine if the file should be compressed or not (JPEG, PNG, and other binary files skip the compress step.)